# Can I merge an XFS partition with another XFS partition?

Tags: xfs

I am using an SSD where I have 3 partitions:

```
$ lsblk  /dev/sda
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     2M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   108G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0   3.8G  0 part /mnt
```

The `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sda3` was formatted as XFS.

I don't need the `/dev/sda3` any more, I don't have any data there, and I want to merge it with /dev/sda2. It's not a big problem if I have to unallocate `/dev/sda2`. But I have important data and the overall OS installed on `/dev/sda2`.

Is there a way to merge /dev/sda3 with /dev/sda2 in a way that the data on `/dev/sda2` remains intact?

**Edit:**

Before asking I have tried xfs_growfs this way:

```
# xfs_growfs /dev/sda2 
meta-data=/dev/sda2              isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=7077888 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=1, sparse=1, rmapbt=0
         =                       reflink=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=28311552, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0, ftype=1
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=13824, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
```

It doesn't do anything. I have also tried deleting partition 3, and then running `xfs_growfs` with both `/` and `/dev/sda2`. I rebooted, and saw that the free space is free, and `/dev/sda2` is 108 GB as always.

I am not using LVM.

Details:

```
xfs_info -V
xfs_info version 5.7.0
```

OS:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release | head -n1
NAME="Arch Linux"
```

Kernel:

```
$ cat /proc/version 
Linux version 5.8.5-xanmod1-1-xanmod (makepkg@archlinux) (gcc (GCC) 10.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.35) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 02 Sep 2020 20:22:18 +0000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No merging is possible of course; what you described on the last paragraph is the proper way to go, plus one step which I missed initially:

- `umount /mnt`, *done*
- delete `sda3` using `fdisk` or `parted`, *done*
- extend partition `sda2`
- extend filesystem using `xfs_growfs /`.

The 3rd step is a bit dangerous. If you have a backup of the system proceed, else use `gparted` iso. On your live system, start `fdisk /dev/sda`. `p` to list the partitions. Write down the start sector of sda2 and the id type. Then `d` to delete it! Next, make a new partition starting from exactly the same sector as before and ending to the last sector of the disk. It'll probably be set to the same id & type, 83 Linux I suppose, but check this also. After you finish `p`, check again that the start sector of new sda2 and id are the same as the old one, `w` `q`. The dangerous part is that if you miss the start or the id, the partition data will be destroyed (well not exactly but you're getting in trouble). Just deleting the partition alters the table, the data are not touched.
After that `xfs_growfs /` will extend the file system; if not a `partprobe` or `partx` command may be needed for the kernel to get informed of the changes. Or you can just reboot.

It may seem odd to delete a partition to extend it, but it's a standard procedure, you can search for it. If you want to avoid it, you can use LVM on future systems.

---

Another way would be to download `gparted` make a boot usb/cd, boot from there and do the job in an easy graphical environment.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted partition 3 using fdisk (the tools I prefer), w, q. Confirmed that partition 3 is deleted using lsblk.

The output from ` lsblk -o name,fstype,size,fssize,mountpoint,label,model,vendor` is here: https://pastebin.com/EPQBwfZm    ... Now if I do `xfs_growfs /` and reboot, nothing happens.

Comment: You are right, a step was missing. I changed my answer.

Comment: Oh wow! That's a real tricky one! Wait, first let me do it in my virtual machine... I will let you know...

Comment: In my VM, I deleted the BIOS boot partition, truncated it from 2 mebibytes to ~970B, installed GRUB, and rebooted. That's fine. Then I tried merging that free space before my /dev/sda2 with the small free space, doing so, I have to forcefully use different starting sector... So isn't it possible to merge partition whose sectors lies before the partition that I am trying to merge? And the system (cloned VM) won't boot now...

Comment: First of all, there's no merging! No, you cannot use sectors before. That messes the layout. You must start at exactly the same sector and end on the same as before or greater, if you want to find the file system(s) inside the partition again! Since you are an enquiring mind regarding partitioning, you can also have NO partitions at all :) On VMs that's what I do, in order to be able to extend them live (without LVM).

Comment: And you know what, your suggestion worked out of the box. I then ran ```dd if=/dev/urandom of=/test_file bs=10M count=1000 status=progress``` dd failed. I learnt the xfs partition, even though has more space now, can't be utilized unless ```xfs_growfs``` is run... Then I ran that on ```/``` and the whole system has more space now!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: On my laptop, I deleted partition 2, created 2 with the extra space, said N to the suggestion of removal of XFS signature by fdisk, w, q. Then I ran xfs_grow, rebooted, working just fine... Didn't even take a backup... I think there's 0 chance of data corruption...